importing WIF key
HI I have not saved my 12 words seed phrase of Unisat wallet but I have the WIF key of my wallet. Can I still access my wallet? or is there any wallet available which have an option of importing wallet with WIF key. and I don't have bitcoin core. I have tried researching online but could not find anything on this topic

My suggestion to you is to use this cryptofuzz in Python and convert WiF Key to mnemonics:
install cryptofuzz : pip install cryptofuzz or pip3 install cryptofuzz
from cryptofuzz import Convertor
cv = Convertor()
WIF_STR = "ENTER_YOUR_WIF_KEY"
mnemonic_str = cv.wif_to_mne(WIF_STR)
print(mnemonic_str)


Please disclose self-promotion.
